# Using Protractor Test with Bootstrapped AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, protractor

I want to be able to test my Angular application with Protractor. Since I use RequireJS, I cannot use `ng-app` directive in my DOM and that is why I bootstrap Angular manually with `angular.bootstrap`.

Protractor prints an error output like below:

> Error: Angular could not be found on the page `http://localhost:1428/` : retries looking for angular exceeded

Then, I realized that Protractor documentation has a warning:

> Protractor does not work out-of-the-box with apps that bootstrap manually using angular.bootstrap. You must use the ng-app directive.

Well, Is there any workaround to run Protractor tests with manually bootstrapped angular application or should I start to learn about alternative testing suites?

Comment: Our protractor tests are working well with RequireJS and manually bootstraped apps. Could you share more code please? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

go to protractor confiuration and add this

```
onPrepare: function() {
// implicit and page load timeouts
  browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
  browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);

  // for non-angular page
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  // sign in before all tests

}
```

It worked for me

my full config file looks like this...

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['../**/*.e2e.js'],
multiCapabilities: [{
browserName: 'firefox'
}],

onPrepare: function() {
// implicit and page load timeouts
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);

// for non-angular page
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

// sign in before all tests

 }
}
```

What actually happens is that you ask from protractor to wait for an amount of time and ignnore the document.ready(), in order to give you time to bootstrap angular manually.

Comment: Not really, this workaround could also work when you bootstrap angular async (My case was that I was passing as dependencies RequireJS modules from another app)

Comment: This is not working for me, it gets the tests working intermittently but other times items are not ready and they fail. (IE I can run the exact same test four times in a row and get one fail.)

Comment: It might have to do with your timeouts