# SystemJS on ready?

Tags: javascript, systemjs

Is there a way to wait until all `System.register`s (transpiled from ES6) are resolved and loaded?

This is especially useful for [e2e testing in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596706/using-protractor-test-with-bootstrapped-angularjs) and other little things.

Answer (score 3):

`System.import` the module you want to wait for which returns a promise.

```
System.import("myModule").then(function() {
   // here it is loaded.
});
```

In practice, you probably want to use something like systemjs-builder with route specific bundling logic rather than load things with system on the first page load - so less round trips are made to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with `System.import().then` is that the second-level dependencies will not get resolved.

`System.register` has a "callback" that is executed when all its dependencies (and dependencies of its dependencies, etc. ) are resolved.

When transpiling from ES6, basically this "callback" constructed from the rest of the code in the file—all the code expect the `import` statements. Therefore, I don't really have to do anything with SystemJS to get a callback to start the tests; the problem is now how to get testing, i.e. Protractor, to start manually. Currently, the workaround is to delay the testing by a fixed ~30 seconds.